# What happened to the prism project linker in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, silverlight, prism, multi-targeting

How do I share files between WPF and Silverlight projects in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The project linker download can be found here **at the bottom of the page in the "Files in this Download" section**:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fa07e1ce-ca3f-4b9b-a21b-e3fa10d013dd&displaylang=en

And just in case you were also asking about its usage, here is a link to the usage information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458870.aspx

Comment: My guess is the questioner is wondering if that project is still usable in VS2010.

Comment: I think you are right.  My mistake... I misread the question.  I'll leave it here for posterity, but since this is a visual studio add-in, it's likely they haven't created the same for VS2010.

Comment: Exactly, so is the add-on compatible with VS2010 or not? We couldn't get it to work. But I'm wondering if it's because of perhaps an issue because of having the VS2010 Beta 2 installed and also VS2008 and also a whole lot of other add-ons and toolkits etc.

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  Addons have to target a version of VS, so this one likely hasn't been updated.

Comment: You can use a Silverlight 4.0 dll class library from .Net 4.0 but not the other way around

Answer (score 6):

You can download Project Linker for Visual Studio 2010 in the Extension Manager. Just search for "Project Linker". It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to have been released as a self installer for VS2010. However, the code does appear to have been updated to allow the plugin to run in VS2010.

Have a look [at this discusson thread](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=73989). About two thirds of the way down the tread, it gets to the point where they give that link and discuss the steps for making it work. Here is the [link to the source code updated for VS2010](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/46111).

The steps to use the code to generate an installer that will work for you are (ripped from the linked thread):

> open solution in vs2010
>   compile as release
>   add a new VSIX project (template located under c#>Extensibility).
>
> In the VSIX project you need to add two "content" items
>   - a "VS Package type" as the output of the project linker project,
>   - a "Custom Extension" Type - as a file and browse to the compiled project linker helper dll

HTH